# Datetime pattern for yyyy.mm.dd.hh.mm.ss pattern code?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

What is the DATE FORMAT CODE for "yyyy.mm.dd.hh.mm.ss"?

I know that 34 (date format code) is "yyyymmddhhmmss", but what about the code for "yyyy.mm.dd.hh.mm.ss"?

This is on SQL 2005.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is your question?

Comment: I want to get the date format as it shown in the title

Comment: the output of the datetime must be as it the following example: 2010.07.21.19.00.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As gbn said, using one of the existing formats with some string concatenation would work. Another option is:

```
SELECT
    CAST(YEAR(my_date) AS CHAR(4)) + '.' +
    RIGHT('0' + CAST(MONTH(my_date) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + '.' +
    RIGHT('0' + CAST(DAY(my_date) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + '.' +
    RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, my_date) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + '.' +
    RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE, my_date) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + '.' +
    RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(SECOND, my_date) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

[CAST and CONVERT on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28SQL.90%29.aspx) says "no".

You have to CONVERT twice with styles 102 and 108, with a concatenation and REPLACE.

Where did you get the "34" date format code from?

Answer (score 1):

Considering

```
 SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), GETDATE(), 120) AS [YYYY-MM-DD] 
 ---returns--- yyyy-mm-dd hh:ss
```

and you can use REPLACE to convert strings

```
 REPLACE('a b c',' ','.')  
 ----returns--- a.b.c
```

and you can recursively stack things you get to this

```
Select (
    replace((replace((replace(CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), GETDATE(), 120),' ','.')), ':', '.')), '-', '.')
    )
```

which returns: `yyyy.mm.dd.hh.ss`

works great for datetime stamps or filenames!